# Again, PHP in Mac OS X: PHP loads source code in browser rather than executing

Tags: php, macos, httpd.conf

I don't know what to do. I read the related question on this site just like mine but those changes didn't work.

First, I edited the httpd.conf file and uncommented the PHP load module line. Next after getting this error "/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 82: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument" I changed `ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n ulimit -H -n` to  `ULIMIT_MAX_FILES=""` or some odd thing. That resolved that error.

Then I finally added `AddType x-httpd-php .php` to the httpd.conf file because that was also mentioned in the previous question here on stackoverflow.

However I still just see my source code in Safari (actually Chrome decided to *download* the PHP file instead--different problem/story). Then I found a question similar to mine on this site and added some AddHandler lines to the php5.conf file which mimicked the AddType lines in the file after AddHandler. Still didn't work even after a "sudo apachectl restart".

I'm baffled. Please help. I'm just trying to get started so I can learn to program and I feel like I've spent a lifetime just trying to print 'Hello World' in my browser.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault, since it's not a programming question - more of a server configuration problem.

Comment: Indeed. You are lacking the PHP module for apache2.  Ask on serverfault how to include it.

Comment: As I said, I have uncommented the PHP module line in the httpd.conf file. I guess I'll go to serverfault.

Comment: You might want to look a free application called 'MAMP', which bundles Apache, PHP and MySQL together in an easy to install app. It's all self-contained and, for me at least, just worked out of the box!

Comment: What URL are you trying to display when you see your code displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a server side script is being served as a file rather than executed as code, it means your server has not been configured properly.  Make sure you have enabled the PHP module in your httpd.conf file and restarted the web server by opening preferences and toggling the "Web Sharing" option in the Sharing pane.

As a commenter noted, however, this is not a programming question but is a server administration question.  Go look at the resources in serverfault.

Comment: Well I figured since the exact same question was posed and answered on here, I would just ask it again and see what happened.

Comment: Aye -- that one doesn't belong here either!  I'm sure there is a great answer on SO.